# How to resolve function name in elf

Tags: elf, relocation

I wanted to write an elf parser and disassemble the .text section, so I parsed the elf file and gave the .text section to the capstone to disassemble it for me. Unfortunately, capstone doesn't resolve function names.

According to the below assembly code in my elf file, there is a call to a function that I want to resolve its name.

`call       8048380`

I checked .symtab section but functions that need relocation like printf has a 0 address in the table because their address is unknown until load time.

So how am I gonna resolve its name?

Answer (score 0):

> I checked .symtab section but functions that need relocation like printf

The function you are interested in (the one at address `0x8048380`) is *not* like `printf` and *doesn't* require runtime relocation.

It's unclear from your question *how* you obtained this dissassembly:

```
call 8048380
```

Chances are you need to use better tool, or you pointed your tool at a stripped binary (don't do *that*).

Here is an example of what the reasonable output should look like:

```
int foo() { return 42; }
int main() { return foo(); }

$ gcc t.c
$ gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048410 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048411 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x08048413 <+3>: call   0x8048406 <foo>  // GDB resolves the address
   0x08048418 <+8>: pop    %ebp
   0x08048419 <+9>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: I wanted to write an elf parser and disassemble the .text section, so I parsed the elf file and gave the .text section to the capstone to disassemble it for me. Unfortunately, capstone doesn't resolve function names.

Comment: @Kavian If you are feeding `.text` to `capstone`, you have no one else but yourself to blame for your difficulty -- it also needs `.symtab` and `.strtab` to decode the symbols.